# Optimizing functions with GAs

Tags: artificial-intelligence, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

Firstly, sorry if this is not the right stack exchange for this question it might fit better on math.

I've been working on a project to maximize a functions output using a GA. However, from the limited calculus I know I thought there were methods to find the maximum of a mathematical function using calculus? I'd assume the reason GAs are sometimes used to maximize functions is because there are functions where the mathematical methods don't work. I wondered what conditions those were? Maybe that it's not continuous or differentiable?

Comment: I would say take it to http://math.stackexchange.com. // From my very limited experience. I think that GA's are more useful in situations with a huge/complex search space, and mathematical approaches are more geared to feasible problems. // Also please link to the question here, I would like to see it.

Comment: @AnotherUser http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887424/optimizing-functions-with-gas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for starters, you don't always have easily differentiable functions.  You may especially have very high dimensional functions, which can be very difficult to differentiate.

Moreover, even if you do have a function you can differentiate, what you find are *local* optima, not global optima, and you may end up finding a great many of them-- potentially infinite numbers of them-- with no clear way to decide which are better than others.

While you may know enough about some particular function to be able to optimize with calculus, there is no method guaranteed to go you the global optimum for any possible function.  Hence we rely on a number of probabilistic techniques and heuristics, of which genetic algorithms are only one.

Answer (score 1):

## A superficial explanation

For simple™ mathematical functions, the solution would be to use your calculus and find the derivate  function *f'(x)*. If it's not mathematically possible to differentiate the error function *f(x)*, you need to break out the other tools from you math-box. If the error function's solution space is convex, you could possibly use a numerical approach to find your optimum such as the [gradient descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) or the [conjugate gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) algorithm.

The Genetic Algorithm (and other search algorithms) comes in handy if the function you are trying to optimize consists of multiple undefined variables. This would make calculating the optimum using calculus very difficult. If you are familiar with Neural Networks: the genetic algorithm has been applied to find optimal weight configurations for neural networks. In these problem instances, there might be thousands of unknown variables (weights).

A mathematical approach would have to search the solution space in some incremental approach, the genetic algorithm is a bit "all over the place"™. By adjusting the mutation frequency, the GA would be able to jump around in the search space.

#### A (oversimplified) difficult solution space:

[image]

Image: [Ciumac Sergiu](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175777/Financial-predictor-via-neural-network)